# Loading a very large number of Sqlite rows into UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

need to load 20,000 items in my UITableView, I wonder what the best way to do this. I'm currently using direct queries in SQLite. This is consuming too much memory and slow leaving the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple options: page the data in transparently or implement something like mail where you click to load 25 more.

**If you page data transparently**

The UITableView has callbacks like total and load data for row so that's perfect, it's virtual and cells are re-used.

But, you can't do a basic select, you have to select x at a time - for example, a page of 50.  You have to first select count(*) for the full query so you know then count.  Then, when the call back asks for row 353, you need to calculate that's page 8 (reading pages of 50), select those 50 and return data for row 353.  When 354 is asked for, you already have page 8 in memory so you return.  You would have to reselect when you cross the page boundary.  Memory is reduced because you're only holding a page of results at a time in memory.

The interesting question is how do you query 50 at a time in a stable manner.  The simplest pattern would be incrementing int ids that are stable.  That depends on your data.  For example, if it's a user based predicate query, how do you persist the 20K so you can proceed to page in 50 at a time?  Without memory, you would be forced to write the results of the user predicate to another table in sqlite.

If you wanted to optimize, you could read ahead to the next page in the direction the user is scrolling (is row asked for incrementing or decrementing?)  That might above pauses on page boundaries.

**If you load 25 more at a time**

That pattern is much simpler.  In the footer of the table, the user can click to load 25 more then you change the total number callback and reload the data.

**Tradeoffs?**

Well, the paging transparently has the benefit of never having more than one (or n) page(s) at a time selected into memory no matter how far the user scrolls.  In the 25 more model, as the user goes deeper and depper into the dataset, it consumes more memory.  The transparent paging is obviously much more complex so you should think about what user experience you want and how far will folks go into the dataset.

One last point, if you have that many rows, you'll want an alphabetical index (or similar concept) so the user can jump through that much data.  You can also go back to the drawing board and think if there's other data or access patterns to avoid 20K rows in a view :)

Comment: you have any examples of how I can implement this behavior when scrolling screen? Would have to implement the following method: indexpathsforvisiblerows?

Comment: I don't have a iOS sample/snippet even though it would be a good blog.  If I do, I'll post back.  I have implemented in other systems.  The is the 'virtual table' with the callbacks.  I think you only need to implement the basic callbacks for count and load cell for index.  You need to create a page loading layer (and unloading) and simply answer those callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't load all of the items into your UI, afterall the user can't read all of them and neither can you display them all.

I would suggest that you load up items in smaller batches and tie them into the scroll events triggered by the user scrolling through the data.

For example if you can display 50 rows of data then load up say 50 rows of data either side of what can be viewed. Then as the user scrolls through the data you reach a point (say row 80) whereby you load up the next 50 rows and drop the first 50 from your UI.